# Обрезание переменной

Tags: php, переменные

Здравствуйте, друзья!

Как выполнить на php обрезание переменное после определённого слова?

К примеру:

обрезание после: admin было: `admin01` стало: `01`

Спасибо огромное заранее всем!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать например функцию [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
str_replace("admin", "", "admin01"); //return "01"
```

Comment: Что за чушь?)
Пользователь вводить значение переменной.
Всё, что после admin должно обрезаться само.

Comment: Не понял комментария выше... Так чем этот вариант не подходит?

Comment: или нужно убрать 01?

Comment: пользователь вводит http://uztest.ru/некоторый текст
нужно получить 'некоторый текст'

Comment: ну так чем функция str_replace не устраивает? И почему вы говорите, что это чушь?

Comment: Всё верно, приношу извинения - ступил.
Спасибо.